# sys.stdin в PyCharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

Какие клавиши нужно нажимать в PyCharm (Python), чтобы прекратить поток sys.stdin?

Comment: Обычно после клика на Enter, sys.stdin отдает введенное в него. Можете подробнее рассказать про ситуацию?

Comment: Не уверен насчёт Pycharm, но везде stdin закрывается на `Ctrl-D`

Comment: Ага, Ctrl + D. Спасибо